# Publishing android library to jcenter error - Add a POM file to the latest version of your package

Tags: android, maven, pom.xml, bintray, jcenter

I am trying to publish my Android library to JCenter using Bintray's web site.

I have created a Maven styled zip file which includes all the needed artifacts: aar, sources, javadocs and pom file using the following blog post:

http://blog.blundell-apps.com/locally-release-an-android-library-for-jcenter-or-maven-central-inclusion/

Everything seems to be in place inside the created zip file but still I get an error when trying to link my package to JCenter:

> Add a POM file to the latest version of your package

I am not sure what's wrong, since a pom is inside..

Any ideas what might be wrong?

**UPDATE:**

This is the content of the zip file:

```
com
└───foxxymobile
    └───wearmock
        └───wear-mock
            │   maven-metadata.xml
            │   maven-metadata.xml.md5
            │   maven-metadata.xml.sha1
            │
            └───0.1.0
                    wear-mock-0.1.0-javadoc.jar
                    wear-mock-0.1.0-javadoc.jar.md5
                    wear-mock-0.1.0-javadoc.jar.sha1
                    wear-mock-0.1.0-sources.jar
                    wear-mock-0.1.0-sources.jar.md5
                    wear-mock-0.1.0-sources.jar.sha1
                    wear-mock-0.1.0.aar
                    wear-mock-0.1.0.aar.md5
                    wear-mock-0.1.0.aar.sha1
                    wear-mock-0.1.0.pom
                    wear-mock-0.1.0.pom.md5
                    wear-mock-0.1.0.pom.sha1
```

And this is the POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.foxxymobile.wearmock</groupId>
  <artifactId>wear-mock</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.0</version>
  <packaging>aar</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
      <artifactId>appcompat-v7</artifactId>
      <version>21.0.3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

AS you can see, the pom is located inside the zip. This is how the script created it.

Comment: Can you please share the contents (file tree) of the zip file and the contents of the pom file?

Comment: Looks like you uploaded everything in one archive but did not explode it

Comment: @JBaruch I have added the zip file contents and the pom as per your request.

Comment: @drorb JCenter say they know how to accept a zip file and extract it on their side... it that true?

Comment: That's very true, if you ask nicely :) It's a checkbox in the UI and flag in REST API.

Comment: Missed the checkbox... Arghhhhh. Thanks, write this as an answer and I will mark it.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see any checkbox.
Anything else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cause of this issue was that all required artifacts were uploaded as a zip archive which was not extracted. For this reason Bintray could not find the required POM fie.
When [manually uploading](https://bintray.com/docs/usermanual/uploads/uploads_manuallyuploadingfilestoaversion.html) content to Bintray, you can upload an archive and choose to extract it by checking the "Explode this archive" checkbox. This checkbox is unchecked by default.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it:

I [manually upload](https://bintray.com/docs/usermanual/uploads/uploads_manuallyuploadingfilestoaversion.html) 2 files to Bintray, in the following name format:

```
[library name]-[version].[type]
```

for example:

```
my-library-name-0.0.3.pom 
my-library-name-0.0.3.aar
```

The file my-library-name-0.0.3.pom is a copy of the generatd file [lib project folder]\build\poms\pom-default.xml, which contains a list of dependencies and stuff.

**Important**: When I upload my-library-name-0.0.3.pom, the system suggested to put it in a specific path - you nedd to put both files there.

After publishing the files, you should see in the package page "Maven build settings (ver: 0.0.3)" and the maven/gradle inport details.